# AWS AppSync oidc authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, aws-appsync

I have added an oidc auth provider for my AppSync application. Users are now authenticated. However, I want to also authorize the users, meaning I want fine grained access control in my schema.

I have seen something about @aws_oidc(groups: ["admin"]) being used. But does not work for me. My idtoken consists of groups, name etc.

How can I setup this using @aws_oidc?

Comment: Any chance you found a solution to this? Running into the same problem

Comment: Sorry. I did go for another approach since I could not figure it out.